# Check a condition in many files from a list - R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of n files with identical columns and I want to subset them based on some conditions which are "captured" in a vector a of the same lenght as the file number, n.

```
    list_files(file_1, file_2, ..., file_n)

    a <- c(1, 2, 3, ....,n).
```

I need to extract from each file those rows which meet a condition related to the same column in each file  (Column_1) and bind them together with

```
  rez[1] <- list_file[[1]] %>%
       filter(Column_1 == a[1])
  rez[2] <- list_file[[2]] %>%
       filter(Column_1 == a[2]),
  .
  .
  .
```

I tried a for loop but I got stucked at the results binding (rbind(rez[1], rez[2],  )
Any help?
Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide us with a reproducible [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) that we can copy and paste to better understand the issue and test possible solutions. You can share datasets with `dput(YOUR_DATASET)` or smaller samples with `dput(head(YOUR_DATASET))`. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610) for some great advice.)

Comment: ... or, since you have a list of frames, perhaps `dput(lapply(rez,head)[1:3])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using data similar to

```
dummy_df <- data.frame(Column_1 = 1:26, Column_2 = LETTERS)
list_file <- list(dummy_df, dummy_df, dummy_df)
a <- c(11:13)
```

you could avoid the loop and use

```
purrr::map2_dfr(list_file, a, ~ dplyr::filter(.x, Column_1 == .y))
```

returning

```
  Column_1 Column_2
1       11        K
2       12        L
3       13        M
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution was perfect. I could solve the issue.